# Sum of series which is not Arithmetic Progression or Geometric Progression

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

What is the sum of following infinite series ?

I am not able to find it as modification of $\sin x$ or $\log(1+x)$ series

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{3x^3} + \dots$$

Comment: what is its derivative?

Comment: Could you write what is AP and GP explicitly.

Comment: What is $$\ln(1-x)=?$$

Comment: @Leth thank you so much. Edited title.

Comment: Hint: make the substitution $y = \frac{1}{x}$ or even $y=-\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @user3794480 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\color{green}\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: @ClementC. I was not aware of this protocol. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

> for $x\notin[-1,1]$, $$
> -\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)
>  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nx^n}.
> $$

**How to get to the result:**
Start with the series for $x\mapsto \ln(1+x)$: For $x\in(-1,1)$,
$$
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}
$$
so, considering $-x$,
$$
\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^nx^n}{n}
 = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
and therefore, for $x\in(-1,1)$,
$$
-\ln(1-x)
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}.
$$
Now, this implies that for $x\notin[-1,1]$,
$$
-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nx^n}.
$$

Comment: thank you. I did not understand what is problem with x = -1 .

Comment: It will also work with $x=-1$. But the argument above tries to be general and simple (operations on power series)-- when manipulating power series, everything is fine *inside* the open disc of convergence, and things need to be checked "manually" on the border. $-1$ is on the border. You can now check that $-\ln 2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ as well, so the expression is true on $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\verts{x} > 1}$:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\,{1 \over nx^{n}}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\,{1 \over x^{n}}\int_{0}^{1}y^{n - 1}\,\dd y =
{1 \over x}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{y \over x}^{n - 1}\,\dd y =
{1 \over x}\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 - y/x}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\vphantom{\Large A}-\ln\pars{\verts{y - x}}
\right\vert_{\ y\ =\ 0}^{\ y\ =\ 1}\,\,\,\,\,\, =\
-\ln\pars{\verts{1 - x \over 0 - x}} =
\color{#f00}{-\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over x}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Your series is $\frac 1x -\frac 1x \int{dx} \left(  \frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1{x^3}+\frac 1{x^4}\dots\right)$  where the first term is special because the constant in the denominator is $1$, which avoids problems with integrating to the log.  Bring the sum inside.